# Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, mean, deviation

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to fix this part of my code where I get the `"TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly"`

```
z = ((a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l)/12)
```

I am running python 3.4.3

If anyone knows what modules I can import for standard deviation or mean that would be helpful

Comment: So what are the values of all the variables involved?

Comment: You seem to be asking two entirely different things; why do you think importing something will solve a type problem?

Comment: Be sure that none of your variable is string.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your variables, at the very least `a`, but extending to `b`, `c`, etc., is a string object. You cannot add a floating point number to the string:

```
>>> '' + 0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

You could just use the [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) to calculate a mean and standard deviation, however; there is both a [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) and a [`stdev()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) available. Just make sure all your variables are proper floats:

```
from statistics import mean, stdev

values = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
float_values = [float(v) for v in values]
mean_value = mean(float_values)
stdev_value = stdev(float_values)
```

Note that it'll be much easier to deal with *one* variable holding a list of those values rather than use 12 separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the same mistake myself many times. Just remember: You can't add different data types together. Here is a great way to combine them though:

```
userID = 5
return userID
userIDcopy = str(userID)
print "Welcome User "+userIDcopy
```

Hope this helps!